# Binding a JavaScript array of dates to a page's view model on form submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I added the following field to my form:

```
<input asp-for="MyDates" type="hidden" name="MyDates" id="MyDates" />
```

In my JavaScript I allow the user to select multiple dates from a schedule and store them in an array. Everytime the array is updated I additionally update the hidden input field's value using JSON.stringify(array). The html ends up looking like this before form submission:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MyDates" id="MyDates" value="[&quot;2016-02-17T05:00:00.000Z&quot;,&quot;2016-02-16T05:00:00.000Z&quot;,&quot;2016-02-11T05:00:00.000Z&quot;,&quot;2016-02-12T05:00:00.000Z&quot;,&quot;2016-02-19T05:00:00.000Z&quot;]">
```

When the user clicks submit I expect these dates to get bound to the IList MyDates property in my ViewModel. Can someone tell me why it is not? Additionally if there is a better way to do things like this please let me know.

Here is what my JavaScript function looks like and it is working... It handles displaying the dates to the user and additionally creating hidden input fields for submission. Is there a better way though?

```
function refreshDates() {
    var dateListHtml = "";
    var baselineDatesHtml = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; ++i) {
        dateListHtml = dateListHtml + dates[i].toLocaleDateString() + ' <i onclick="removeDate(' + i + ')" class="fa fa-minus-circle pull-right" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></span>' + '<br>';
        baselineDatesHtml = baselineDatesHtml + '<input asp-for="MyDates" type="hidden" name="MyDates" id="MyDates" value="' + dates[i].toLocaleDateString() + '" />';
    }
    $("#dateList").html(dateListHtml);
    $('#myDates').html(baselineDatesHtml);
}
```

Comment: The number of dates user can select, do you know it  ? Is it n ? How are you handling it in UI ? multiple input fields ?

Comment: I have a calendar on the screen. When the user clicks a date on the calendar the value gets added to a JavaScript array. I am using a Kendo UI for MVC Calendar widget along with custom JavaScript to create an array of the dates the user picks.

Comment: Are you doing an ajax form post or normal form submit ?

Comment: Normal form submit to the controller.

Comment: The MVC binding mechanism is failing because it either expects a 1-1 mapping between the input element and the myDates variable or it is failing to parse the stringify value that you stuffed into the value prop.  I would make the myDates field on the server side a string type and parse it on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For model binding to work, your form element's name should match with the your view model property name(s)/hierarchy. So if you are doing a normal form submit, it is best if you add a new form element to your form ( a hidden element) and store the value there. As long as you have the name attribute value matching with the view model property name, model binding will simply work.

Assuming you have a view model like this

```
public class CreatePost
{
   public IList<DateTime> MyDates { set; get; }
   //Some other properties for the view
}
```

Now, lets create a javascript method which will create a new form element and append that to the form.The below example assumes you included jQuery in your page.

```
function addHiddenDate(dateString) {
    var itemCount = $("input.myDates").length;
    var dat = $("<input type='hidden' class='myDates'
                                 name='MyDates[" + itemCount++ + "]' />").val(dateString);
    $("form").append(dat);
}
```

And whenver user add's a new date, instead of adding to the array, call this method and pass the date value.

```
$(function(){

  $("#addBtn").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     addHiddenDate($("#DateInputField").val());
  });

});
```

Now when you submit the form, Model binding will correctly map the posted form data to the action method parameter, assuming the parameter is of type `CreatePost`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreatePost model)
{
  // check model.MyDates 
  // to do   : Return something
}
```

Comment: Ahh so you are saying for each date in the array a hidden input field needs to be created. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. With that you do not need to override the form submit behavior. Model binding will work fine.

Comment: I didn't realize your example was an addFunction so everytime the user clicks add you add a hidden input field to the form. I get it!

Comment: Can you see my updated JavaScript and let me know if it makes sense because it is working. I just want to make sure there isn't a simpler way.

Comment: Where did i say that ? Your input name should be like `MyDates[0]`, `MyDate[1]` etc up to `MyDate[n]` where n is the number of dates you want to send.

Comment: Also, you do not need `asp-for` and `Id` attribute when you build the markup from javascript !

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks like you are setting the value to the name attribute which is confusing me.. Shouldn't it be the value attribute?

Comment: I am calling the jQuery `val()` method to set the date value.  why don't you try the code i provided as it is and see the generated markup  ?

Comment: I got it I was reading it wrong sorry. Thanks for all of the help and the perfect answer.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of what a remove function would look like? Something like: $("form").remove("input.myDates[" + index + "]");??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102521/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-shyju).